# How to get the dropzone object

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have a form

```
<form action="server.php" class='dropzone' id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

I need to access this dropzone to get the response from the server.

Ive tried...

```
$('#my-awesome-dropzone').on('success',function(file, response){
    //STUFF TO DO HERE
});
```

But it appears Im not getting the actual dropzone object, just the jquery object, which means I dont have access to the 'success', 'addedfile' callbacks.

Anyone know how I can access this dropzone via a jquery selector?? What is the proper way to do that?

PS I know how to instantiate via javascript, and do it like that.  But I wanna know how to access an already formed dropzone, since in my situation now, this is the only real option.

Comment: Have you tried doing `console.log(Dropzone);` to see if it's already an object? It _seems_ like dropzone.js creates `Dropzone` as a global variable.

Comment: Or perhaps you could just do `var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});` with the dropzone div you've already created and see what happens. It might just attach itself. I feel for you though, Dropzone's documentation looks to be pretty terrible.